# How to write to the external storage in android that will be present even after the application is uninstalled?

Tags: android, storage, android-external-storage

I am trying to build an application in which user can share media files over internet. Now I am confused that there are lots of functions in the library through which we can get access to files stored in the users storage. I don't know which to use..

In [Context#getExternalFilesDir(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) documentation, they insist using Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() to write media that must be shared with other apps and that must be kept even after uninstall of an app. But in [Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(string)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) documentation, they say that this method is deprecated, and recommend using alternatives such as Context.getExternalFilesDir(). If that was deprecated in first place, then why did they insist to use that method. What is the reason behind them playing these tricks, I don't understand.

Please suggest me a function that is: not deprecated, should return a directory where I can read and write, media stored there should be visible to other apps, they must not be deleted when user uninstalles this app.

Comment: "If that was deprecated in first place, then why did they insist to use that method" -- not all documentation gets updated at the same time. You could file a bug report suggesting that they update the `getExternalFilesDir()` documentation. "Please suggest me a function" -- there is none that meet your requirements. Since you appear to be working with media, consider [using `MediaStore`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/12/21/scoped-storage-stories-storing-mediastore.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare using mediastore? Can you please answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64730774/how-to-retrieve-a-single-media-file-from-external-storage-using-mediastore) question...... All I want is a File instance so that I can download media into that file.

Comment: @CommonsWare i gone through your post.. Helped a lot. But what is the alternative for `RELATIVE_PATH` constant in lower apis. Please help me

Comment: Most likely, you wind up using separate strategies for older and newer devices. On Android 10+ (or even 11+), use `MediaStore` and `RELATIVE_PATH`. On older devices, use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`. That is the approach that I used in [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/tree/vFINAL/ConferenceVideos).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [Shared Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared).

Answer (score 0):

Android file system and storage changed a lot during this years.

[Data and file storage overview](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)